# Full calendar loading eventSource, Days are presented not in correct place

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I load the data to the eventSource through Ajax call,
then i retrieve the data as..
[image: i received as the response of Ajax call in event Source]

```
eventSources:
        [

            // your event source
            {


                url: '/ajax-load-holidaysExtra',// use the `url` property
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: "JSON",
                data : function()
                { // a function that returns an object
                    var date =  new Date($('#calendar1').fullCalendar('getDate'));
                    month_integer = date.getMonth();
                    year_integer = date.getFullYear();
                    return {
                        month: month_integer,
                        year: year_integer
                    }
                },

                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching eventsin hol!');
                },
                color: 'rgba(244, 221, 38, 0.20)',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'blue' // a non-ajax option

            }

        ],
```

but i get the days which are shown in the calendar is not correct, it shows a date 1 or 2 days before the date which i intend to take from the eventSource..

I am new to full calendar please can anyone help...it will be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

Even the data was correct the format was not okay with the calendar...

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'Event1',
        start: '2011-04-04'
    },
    {
        title: 'Event2',
        start: '2011-05-05'
    }
    // etc...
],
```

as in the documentation the month should be come as `2011-04-04` , but in my data it is `2011-4-4` so the result comes but full calendar shows a another day.

..hope this might be useful to someone, So that's why i keep this Question..if any suggestion open for discussion...